# How to create a .R file from executing a .R file

Tags: r

I thought this would be simple to do, but apparently it isn't as straight forward as I thought.

I want to generate a .R file from the execution of another .R file.

I have tried running the following code:

```
temp = "library(data.table)
x = c(1:3)
x = data.table(x)
"
save(temp, file = 'Write_Script_Test.R')
```

It does create the file; however, when I open the file it is just a bunch of encoded gibberish.

The desired result is the new .R file that contains the contents of the "temp" object:

```
library(data.table)
x = c(1:3)
x = data.table(x)
```

Comment: I think you should read about `writeLines`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `save()` is useful for saving R objects in binary format. If you're looking to generate a text file, the solution is the one Kevin Arseneau gave you. You must use [`writeLines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/writeLines.html) as follows:

```
temp = "library(data.table)
x = c(1:3)
x = data.table(x)
"
writeLines(text=temp, con='Write_Script_Test.R')
```

You can configure an absolute or relative path for the file using the parameter `con`.